# How to create coordinates [x, y] from a list of lists

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

Beginner here. In our genetic course, we are asked to use Excel to create a plot, but I want to do it with Python. When I try to do a scatter plot, I get the line `x=y`. I think that I have to set my data as coordinate like

```
 data = [
    [1, 2],
    [3, 2],
    [4, 7],
    [2, 4],
    [...],
    ]

    x, y = zip(*data)
    plt.scatter(x, y)
    plt.show()
```

as shown elsewhere. But I am struggling to do just that.

I did this for now, but I don't know how to use those two lists as `[x, y]` and then plot.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def read_csvfile(file):
    df = pd.read_csv(file, sep=';', header=0)
    return df
   
cal = read_csvfile('Genotypage_BCM2531_snp49.csv')
x = cal['Signal_FAM']
y = cal['Signal_VIC']

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

But I want to have clusters of coordinates [x,y], and it should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Try adding `decimal=','` to the `read_csv` call.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
x,y = list(zip(*data))

plt.scatter(x,y)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: as BigBen pointed out, I only needed to add   decimal=',' to the read_csv call and it worked just fine. But thanks, good to know that I can use list(zip(*data))